# How to fix my Function so it works in my Tkinter Application (Guessing Game)

Tags: python, list, button, tkinter

Basically, I want to go through answers and check every time if that's correct with a button and then pop it from the list. In another file/code/application it's working when I try to use it on my Gui Application it doesn't iterate and only keeps the first answer right.

I tried multiple things like using Dictionaries and getting the key but it still doesn't iterate over after the Button press.

This is the code that works fine:

```
while answers == True:
answers = ["Sayajin", "Namek", "Cell", "TournamentOfPower"]
for a in  range(4):

    s = input()
    if s in answers[0]:
        print("Richtig")
        answers.pop(0)
```

This is the code that doesnt work:

```
def check(event):
answers = ["Sayajin", "Namek", "Cell", "TournamentOfPower"]
for a in range(4):

    s = entrysaga.get()
    if s in answers[0]:
        print("Richtig")
        answers.pop(0)
```

Complete Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import time
import random

root = Tk()

#Hint Button
hint = Button(root, text= "Hint")
hint.bind("<Button-1>")
hint.place(x=50, y=20)

#How to Play Button + Info Message how to play

def Howtoplay():
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("How to play", "To start the game u have 
to press the button (Start)\n--------------------------------------------- 
----------------\n"
                                           ""
                                           "Then the Picture will switch 
and its going to show u a Character and u have to guess from which Dragon 
Ball Saga he is.\n-------------------------------------------------------- 
-----\n"
                                           "Just type it in the Entry and 
press Check after that if u were right the next picture shows up")

info = Button(root, text="How to Play", command=Howtoplay)
info.bind("<Button-1>")
info.place(x=150, y=20)

#textwidget
textwidget = Label(root, text="Entry the DragonBall Saga:")

#entry widget
entrysaga = Entry(root)

#Pictures for guessing the Saga
Sayajin = PhotoImage(file="sayajinsaga.png")
Namek = PhotoImage(file="NamekSaga.png")
Cell = PhotoImage(file="CellSaga.png")
Buu = PhotoImage(file="BuuSaga.png")
TournamentOfPower = PhotoImage(file="TournamentOfPowersaga.png")

#Start function
def start():
    labelSagas.config(image=Sayajin)


#define check for pictures
def check(event):
    answers = ["Sayajin", "Namek", "Cell", "TournamentOfPower"]
    for a in range(4):

        s = entrysaga.get()
        if s in answers[0]:
            print("Richtig")
            answers.pop(0)

#button check
buttonsaga = Button(root, text="Check")
buttonsaga.bind("<Button-1>", check)

textwidget.place(x=300, y=170)
entrysaga.place(x=300, y= 200)
buttonsaga.place(x=440, y=195)

#Start Button
start = Button(root, text="Start", command=start)
start.bind("<Button-1")
start.place(x=400, y=20)

# Label with start picture,
startpic = PhotoImage(file="dbzsagas.png")
labelSagas = Label(root, image=startpic)
labelSagas.place(x=25, y=80)



#size of window
root.geometry("500x280")

#window title
root.title("Dragon Ball Saga´s guessing game")

#start of the window
root.mainloop()
```

My excepted output should be like in the first code that it iterates over and after getting the first answer right ur on to the next one. But the actual result it that stays on the first.

Comment: Please can you post your complete code? Would be useful to know where `entrysaga` comes from.
Are you getting any errors when running this?

Comment: Hello, I have added the complete code and no I dont get any Errors the programm works but just doesnt iterate over the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have moved the widgets which should appear when you press the `Start` button. They are all in the `def start():` function as they would not appear otherwise.

As `entrysaga` was being called within a different function it could not find the inputted value as the variable is not a global variable. By using `global entrysaga` it means that it is and can be called from anywhere within the script.

This is how it looks:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import time
import random

root = Tk()

#Hint Button
hint = Button(root, text= "Hint")
hint.bind("<Button-1>")
hint.place(x=50, y=20)

#How to Play Button + Info Message how to play

def Howtoplay():
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("How to play", "To start the game u have to press the button (Start)\n--------------------------------------------- ----------------\n"
                                           ""
                                           "Then the Picture will switch and its going to show u a Character and u have to guess from which Dragon Ball Saga he is.\n-------------------------------------------------------- -----\n"
                                           "Just type it in the Entry and press Check after that if u were right the next picture shows up")

info = Button(root, text="How to Play", command=Howtoplay)
info.bind("<Button-1>")
info.place(x=150, y=20)

#Pictures for guessing the Saga
Sayajin = PhotoImage(file="sayajinsaga.png")
Namek = PhotoImage(file="NamekSaga.png")
Cell = PhotoImage(file="CellSaga.png")
Buu = PhotoImage(file="BuuSaga.png")
TournamentOfPower = PhotoImage(file="TournamentOfPowersaga.png")

#Start function
def start():
    labelSagas.config(image=Sayajin)
    global entrysaga
    entrysaga = tkinter.Entry(root)
    entrysaga.place(x=300, y= 200)
    buttonsaga = Button(root, text="Check")
    buttonsaga.bind("<Button-1>", check)
    buttonsaga.place(x=440, y=195)
    textwidget = Label(root, text="Entry the DragonBall Saga:")
    textwidget.place(x=300, y=170)
#define check for pictures
def check(event):
    answers = ["Sayajin", "Namek", "Cell", "TournamentOfPower"]
    for a in range(4):

        s = entrysaga.get()
        if s in answers[0]:
            print("Richtig")
            answers.pop(0)

#Start Button
start = Button(root, text="Start", command=start)
start.bind("<Button-1")
start.place(x=400, y=20)

# Label with start picture,
startpic = PhotoImage(file="dbzsagas.png")
labelSagas = Label(root, image=startpic)
labelSagas.place(x=25, y=80)

#size of window
root.geometry("500x280")

#window title
root.title("Dragon Ball Saga´s guessing game")

#start of the window
root.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Well i have tried it and it still works the same. I also added after answers.pop(0) print(answers) and it shows in the console that it got popped but when i try to write "Namek" and check again it still doesnt work it doesnt call "Richtig".Tthe only thing that works is "Sayajin" again even tho i got popped the function just redoes it. Do i maybe have to do it in another Function and basically append the answer somewhere in another Variable and then try to check it?

Comment: The reason why only "Sayajin" works is because of `if s in answers[0]:` if you remove the `[0]` then anything in that list will call "Richtig" (even if not the correct answer). What you need to do is call the image and then match the entry to the image, so only when the image and `entrysaga.get()` match it will pass.
Or, you can change `[0]` to match the answer in the list, so if the image was "Namek" you change `[0]` to `[1]`. This could be achieved in an `if` statement.